# “Android license status unknown” in flutter doctor

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I am getting an error with Android Sdk when I run `flutter doctor` on command-line

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.4.9-hotfix.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

After following several possible fixes from the stackoverflow community, i still couldn't get it to work.
Please i need assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me

### Fix 1:

- Launch Android studio & Open the SDK manager (Top-right of Android studio)
- Navigate to SDK Tab and look for Android SDK Platform-Tools
- If it's checked, unchecked it and click 'Apply' (We're trying to uninstall the previous version)
- Now the "SDK Tools" is uninstalled. Let's re-install it by checking the box and clicking 'Apply'
- Hit Ok & Restart Android studio
- Navigate to SDK install location at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` for windows, you should see a new folder `tools`
  **Note: If you don't see the `tools` folder don't panic, i got you covered.**
- Open the `tools` folder & navigate to `bin`
- Copy the folder path (i.e `C:\Users\USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`)
- Add that path to Environmental variables
- Now you should have access to `sdkmanager` in the command-line. Try it out by typing `sdkmanager` & hitting enter in CMD.
- If you get `'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` you probably made a mistake while adding the path to System Environmental Variables. Fix that.
- Go to Flutter sdk folder (i.e `c:/src/flutter`) & launch the `flutter_console.bat` file
- Now type the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and it should work. Accept all by typing `y` and hitting ENTER
- And don't forget to run `flutter doctor`

### Fix 2:

*PS: Only if Fix 1 does not work for you!*

- Open your browser & goto [Command line tools only](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) (bottom of the page)
- Download the appropriate package for your platform
- Unzip it & Yes! You should see the `tools` folder
- After extraction, copy the `tools` folder to `C:\Users\USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

  **Now the same as Fix 1 above,**
- Open the `tools` folder & navigate to `bin`
- Copy the folder path (i.e `C:\Users\USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`)
- Add that path to Environmental variables
- Now you should have access to `sdkmanager` in the command-line. Try it out by typing `sdkmanager` & hitting enter in CMD.
- If you get `'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` you probably made a mistake while adding the path to System Environmental Variables. Fix that.
- **NO** you're not done
- The SDK Platform tools you downloaded is probably outdated (as you can see when you run the `sdkmanager` command from the command-line)
- Now let's handover to Android Studio to do the rest. Restart Android Studio, so it can recognize the `tools` folder you added.
- After Restart, Android Studio should automatically detect the outdated Platform-tools and prompt you to update (You must be connected to the internet!).
- IF UPDATE PROMPT DOES NOT SHOW UP
- Open SDK Manager in Android studio,
- Go to UPDATES
- Click `Check Now`
- And you should get the PROMPT to update Platform-Tools

#### Fix 3:

- **Do everything in Fix 2**
- Open Environmental Variables, Create a new Variable `JAVA_HOME` and set the value to the JRE/bin (get it from Android studio install location in Program Files)
- Open the command line type `set JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'` for windows & `export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'` for Linux

And that's it you can now run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` on the command-line; Accept all licenses by typing `y` and hitting ENTER. And don't forget to run `flutter doctor`

#### THAT'S THE FIX. I HOPE IT WORKS FOR YOU TOO