# Android licenses in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

Everything was working fine 4 days ago - I did an update and the licenses stopped going through... what I did so far.

1. the tools obsolete thing is checked -> does not work
2. flutter doctor --android-licenses -> does not work
3. sdkmanager --licenses -> did not work
4. uninstall and reinstall android at least 3 times -> did not work
5. downloaded manually cmdline-tools folder and put in the Sdk folder -> did not work
6. delete folder tools and replaced with new one -> did not work

**flutter doctor**

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Flutter 1.17.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e6b34c2b5c (7 days ago) • 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
Engine • revision 540786dd51
Tools • Dart 2.8.1

$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.7+10, mixed mode)

Android Studio 3.6.3

Comment: Hey Anne, check out my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869110/android-license-status-unknown-in-flutter-doctor/60869111#60869111

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem just recently. I solved mine with the ANDROID_HOME path in the Environment Variables.

[image]

Comment: Just found out the problem was the Android and the openJDK 11 - with jdk1.8 it worked fine...I´ll do what you said, I think it will sort out the problem - feed back in a sec.... many thanks!

Comment: I set the variable ANDROID_HOME and path to the tools and platform-tools.
Still not working.... when I changed the openJDK to java jdk8 the licenses where ok. Now I pinned the problem: is the openJDK11 + android -> PROBLEM STILL THERE :(

Comment: Note that openJDK11 + Android was working fine till 6 days ago... So, downgrade to jdk 8 is not an option for the projects.

Comment: It worked on Linux, using `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`

Answer (score -1):

my solution for the licenses - after 6 days...
uninstall everything JAVA AS WELL.
then reinstall javaSE (jdk8) and reinstall everything openJDK11 as JAVA_home path.
flutter doctor will ask you to do --android-license .

Comment: there is a easier solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869110/android-license-status-unknown-in-flutter-doctor/60869111#60869111