# exception in thread "main" Error during flutter setup

Tags: java, flutter

this is my first time here. I have just started to learn flutter and wanted to set it up on my laptop with windows os. I would appreciate if someone could help me out with this as I have been stuck at this for a couple of days. I am facing this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajFRL.png)

Comment: `javax.xml.bind.annotation` has been removed from JRE in Java9+, so I guess your flutter installation is not compatible with later JRE. Similar (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699046/android-licenses-in-flutter) suggesting same

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Android Studio**
2. Go to **Tools** > **SDK Manager**

A pop up window will appear.

3. From the left navigation, go to **Appearance & Behavior** > **Systems settings** > **Android SDK**
4. On the right select the **SDK Tools** tab
5. Check **Android SDK Command-line tools**
6. Click **Apply**

[image]

7. Run **flutter doctor** command